# Python Matplotlib remove xlabels but not grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, axes

Is there a way to remove the labels of the x axis, but not the grid lines?

Both solutions to remove the labels also removed my grid lines.

I tried: `axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)` and `axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `axes.xaxis.set_tick_params(label1On=False)`